# rails scaffold_controllerで作成したけど、ルートがおかしいです。

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby on Railsで開発しています。
中身はいらなく、ルートの動きだけを見たかったんですが、ルートがおかしいです。

現在の状態としては、

```
rails generate scaffold_controller Home
```

して、routes.rbファイルに `resource :homes` を追加した後、[http://0.0.0.0:3000/homesで実行してみたらindexファイルに行くはずなのにshowファイルに行ってしまうんです](http://0.0.0.0:3000/homes%E3%81%A7%E5%AE%9F%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6%E3%81%BF%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89index%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F%E3%81%AF%E3%81%9A%E3%81%AA%E3%81%AE%E3%81%ABshow%E3%83%95%E3%82%A1%E3%82%A4%E3%83%AB%E3%81%AB%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%97%E3%81%BE%E3%81%86%E3%82%93%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99)。

理由を教えていただけますか？
index画面に行く方法もお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resources :homes` としてください。`resource` は単数形リソースを定義する場合に利用します。

参考: [Rails のルーティング](http://railsguides.jp/routing.html)